# Is there a way to override which control a keystroke is sent to?

Tags: vb.net, controls, keystroke

For the server version of my chat app I have two controls in the form: an `Input` `TextBox` to type in for chatting and a `ClientList` `CheckedListBox` where I can select connected clients in order to do various actions to them (such as muting, kicking, etc).

Here are the `Handlers` for the events associated with these controls:

```
Private Sub Input_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Input.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then

        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

        Send.PerformClick()

        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ClientList_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ClientList.KeyPress

    If e.KeyChar <> " " Then

        Input.Select()

        SendKeys.Send(e.KeyChar)
    End If
End Sub
```

(Note that `Send` is a button which sends the input to the chat)

While `ClientList` has focus: As you can see in `ClientList_KeyPress`, I want any `KeyPresses` which aren't related to `ClientList` to be sent to `Input`. (Only the spacebar and arrow keys are needed to navigate and select items in `ClientList`)

Although the above code works as desired, I feel that it is an inelegant way of doing this. Using `SendKeys` doesn't delegate the `KeyPress` — it just simply sends another keystroke to the application and it feels like poor coding. If the code is changed slightly so that it is more complex and runs async, then there could be the possibility of endless keystrokes being sent if `Input.Select` fails for whatever reason or `ClientList` ends up being focused again.

So I would like a suggestion which intercepts the `KeyStroke` before it is sent to the focused control or a suggestion which triggers the `Input.KeyPress` event in `ClientList_KeyPress` (ie. delegation).

I haven't been able to find anything from my own research — the above code using `SendKeys` is all I can find.

Comment: Keys like Escape and Enter should be intercepted before they reach the control with the focus.  Use the form's AcceptButton and CancelButton properties or override ProcessCmdKey().  Regular keystrokes should be clearly visible in the control that has the focus and not redirected and easy to correct with keys like Backspace and Delete.  In general a TextBox.  Be sure that the user can easily focus with the Tab key.

Comment: @HansPassant There are multiple buttons on my form including `Send` for the chat which could be activated by Enter depending on which TextBox has focus, so I don't think I can implement that. I don't understand how the other things you say are relevant to my question...

Comment: Impossible to see why, setting the form's AcceptButton property to the Send button is already enough.  If you need a custom scheme (don't confuse the user) then override ProcessCmdKey and use the ActiveControl property.  Ask somebody else to operate your UI, best way to get constructive feedback.

Comment: @HansPassant OK — I've never overriden/used ProcessCmdKey so I'll look into that as it sounds like a better way of processing Enter/Esc. But what about sending a keystroke to another control when `ClientList` is focused?